# How to sort by timestamp difference in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sorting, timestamp

suppose I have the following table:

```
name        birth(timestamp)          death(timestamp)
--------   ----------------------   ---------------------
person1      22-05-2013 21:59:00     22-05-2013 21:59:00
person2      20-05-2013 21:58:58     27-06-2025 21:59:55
```

how can I sort this table in a way that it returns the longest-lived person first?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) See [about Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the table is named `people`:

`SELECT * FROM people ORDER BY DATEDIFF( death, birth ) DESC`

For a more precise calculation, use `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` and specify the unit of measurement:

`SELECT * FROM people ORDER BY TIMESTAMPDIFF( MINUTE, birth, death ) DESC`

Here the later date is supplied last, and the earlier date first (backward from `DATEDIFF()`).

The `DATEDIFF()` function calculates the number of days between parameter 1 minus parameter 2. By ordering DESC (descending) we are instructing MySQL to return the largest # of days first.

Here is the MySQL reference on the `DATEDIFF()` function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

And for `TIMESTAMPDIFF()`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff

Comment: Thank you so much, but for my case, the differences will mostly be minutes, or hours, so I need a Time Difference function. But does DATEDIFF() recognizes differences less than one day?